# Geojson map with highcharts

Tags: highcharts, geojson

I have a map in geo json file, which I need to use for the highchart. How can I use the geojson map which I created in the highcharts instead of using given maps in highcharts.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Highcharts.geojson` method to restructure a GeoJSON object in preparation to be read directly by the series.mapData option.

```
  const states = Highcharts.geojson(geojson, 'map'),
    rivers = Highcharts.geojson(geojson, 'mapline'),
    cities = Highcharts.geojson(geojson, 'mappoint');
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gqebvL2t/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.geojson